# Custom font for all UIButtons

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, fonts, uibutton

I have tried:

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIButton class], nil] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TwinkleStarROB" size:24.0]];
```

And it works good on iOS 6, but on iOS 5 font is not displayed well. It is only displayed once clicked on it.

Image examples:
On app load: [Image on app load](http://cl.ly/image/1W0n0O2Y2t0R)
When clicked on: [Image when clicked on](http://cl.ly/image/04473w2i2L3C)

What seems to be the problem?

I get this in console when the app runs, but don't know how to fix it:

> "button text attributes only respected for UIControlStateNormal,
>   UIControlStateHighlighted and UIControlStateDisabled. state = 1 is
>   interpreted as UIControlStateHighlighted."

Comment: Why not alter the font of the `UILabel` instance direct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created IBOutlet for all buttons and changed the font on it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better way to alter the font of a `UILabel` is to do so directly on each label.

```
UILabel* label = ....;

label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TwinkleStarROB" size:24.0]
```

Just make sure you sized your `UILabel` to handle the larger font.

Comment: You mean button.title.font...
I have created the IBOutlet and changed font

Comment: Yes, for a button label you gain access through the `title` property.